# Better way to iterate through nested JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, loops, object, nested

Im trying to arrange the timetable for all the classes in the obj below:

```
{"COSC1121":{
    "name":"Course 1 name",
    "color":"#1ABC9C",
    "type":{
        "lecture":{
            "0":{
                "building":"31",
                "day":0,
                "starttime":1,
                "endtime":3
            }
            "1":{
                "building":"95",
                "day":3,
                "starttime":6,
                "endtime":8
            }
        }
    },
    "priority":0,
    "arranged":true
},
"POPP1112":{
    "name":"Course 2 name",
    "color":"#1ABC9C",
    "type":{
        "lecture":{
            "0":{
                "building":"71",
                "day":2,
                "starttime":2,
                "endtime":4
            }
        },
        "tutorial":{
            "0":{
                "building":"13",
                "day":3,
                "starttime":1,
                "endtime":3
            }
            "1":{
                "building":"80",
                "day":3,
                "starttime":2,
                "endtime":5
            }
            "2":{
                "building":"56",
                "day":3,
                "starttime":7,
                "endtime":9
            }
        }
    },
"priority":1,
"arranged":true
}
}
```

Each **COURSE** has multiple different class **TYPE** and each class **TYPE** has multiple **OPTION** (with different building, day, starttime, endtime). But each **TYPE** of each **COURSE** only has 1 option to be arranged into the timetable.

*For example*: course code **COSC1121** has only 1 TYPE is **lecture**, and this lecture has **2 options** => only arrange 1 of that 2

What I have tried:

```
$.each(that_obj, function(i){

    var this_c_code = that_obj[i].code,
        this_c_name = that_obj[this_c_code].name,
        this_c_color = that_obj[this_c_code].color;

        that_obj[this_c_code].arranged = true;

        $.each( that_obj[this_c_code].type, function(ii) {

            // ii now is the string of course_type (lecture...)

            $.each( that_obj[this_c_code].type[ii], function(iii) {

                // Create short name
                var this_temp_class_opt = that_obj[this_c_code].type[ii][iii];

                var update_result = c_set_timetable_occupy( this_temp_class_opt, this_c_name, this_c_code, ii, this_c_color );

                // Check the update_result and add this class option into another object
                ...
            });
        });
    });
```

That's block of code just loop through that_obj and arrange the first option of each class type. It works just fine.

Now I want it to loop through all possible arrangement (all possibility) like:

1/ Choose COSC1121 -> lecture 0 and 1st option for the rest

2/ Choose COSC1121 -> lecture 1 ...

3/ ...

n/ Choose COSC1121 -> lecture 0 AND POPP1112 -> tutorial 1 (2nd option) ...

SO ON...

Currently get stuck on this one. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

P/S: The output format should be the same as the original object format, just strip out the un-selected options. For instance:

```
{
    0: {
        "COSC1121":{
            "name":"Course 1 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"31",
                        "day":0,
                        "starttime":1,
                        "endtime":3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "POPP1112":{
            "name":"Course 2 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"71",
                        "day":2,
                        "starttime":2,
                        "endtime":4
                    }
                },
                "tutorial":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"13",
                        "day":3,
                        "starttime":1,
                        "endtime":3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    1: {
        "COSC1121":{
            "name":"Course 1 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "1":{
                        "building":"95",
                        "day":3,
                        "starttime":6,
                        "endtime":8
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "POPP1112":{
            "name":"Course 2 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"71",
                        "day":2,
                        "starttime":2,
                        "endtime":4
                    }
                },
                "tutorial":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"13",
                        "day":3,
                        "starttime":1,
                        "endtime":3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    2: {
        "COSC1121":{
            "name":"Course 1 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"31",
                        "day":0,
                        "starttime":1,
                        "endtime":3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "POPP1112":{
            "name":"Course 2 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"71",
                        "day":2,
                        "starttime":2,
                        "endtime":4
                    }
                },
                "tutorial":{
                    "1":{
                        "building":"80",
                        "day":3,
                        "starttime":2,
                        "endtime":5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    3: {
        "COSC1121":{
            "name":"Course 1 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"31",
                        "day":0,
                        "starttime":1,
                        "endtime":3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "POPP1112":{
            "name":"Course 2 name",
            "color":"#1ABC9C",
            "type":{
                "lecture":{
                    "0":{
                        "building":"71",
                        "day":2,
                        "starttime":2,
                        "endtime":4
                    }
                },
                "tutorial":{
                    "2":{
                        "building":"56",
                        "day":3,
                        "starttime":7,
                        "endtime":9
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a faint idea of what you might need. You seem to need possible combinations of all the options between classes. To verify before I write an answer, can you create a json object which should be the output?

Comment: Hi @CharlieH, pls refer my edited post above. Thanks

Comment: The only difference between your input and output is that the output doesn't have any item beyond the 0th one under "type". So, basically you need to iterate through the object and remove all additional item  - but keep the 0th one?

Comment: @CharlieH, no no, maybe there is misunderstanding here. The difference between the in and output is that the output doesnot contains the un-selected class type (stripped out). Therefore, the output is an bigger obj, contains all possibilities, each possibility is an copy (simplified) of input obj

Comment: Ya I see the comment `//second possibility`. Please show me those possibilities too.

Comment: @CharlieH just updated the output, thanks